# Сохранить результат функции jq в переменную bat файла

Tags: json, bat

Есть json в переменной json, необходимо получить phone, записав это значение в переменную phone

```
{
  "ID": "31516",
  "phone": "79999999999",
  "message": "Hello"
}
```

Пробовал

```
set phone = %json% | jq ".phone"
echo phone %phone% phone
```

В консоли выводится пустота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для сохранения значения поля "phone" из JSON-объекта, которое было получено с помощью команды `jq`, в переменную внутри bat-файла, можно использовать следующий синтаксис:

```
   @echo off

   set JSON={"ID": "31516", "phone": "79999999999", "message": "Hello"}

   for /f "delims=" %%i in ('echo %JSON% ^| jq -r ".phone"') do set phone=%%i

   echo phone=%phone%
```

Здесь мы используем команду `for /f`, чтобы выполнить команду `jq` и сохранить ее вывод в переменную phone. В данном случае мы используем опцию `delims=` для того, чтобы обойти проблему с разделением строк, которая может возникнуть при чтении вывода команды `jq`.

Обратите внимание, что в этом примере мы используем одинарные кавычки для обозначения аргумента, который будет передан внутри командной строки `for /f`. Двойные кавычки используются для обозначения строки, переданной в `jq` для извлечения значения поля "phone" из JSON-объекта.

В итоге, мы записываем значение поля "phone" в переменную `phone` и выводим ее значение с помощью команды `echo`.

Ответ на комментарий Дмитрий:

> Использовал ваш код и выдало ошибку "parse error: Expected separator
> between values at line 1, column 22"

Ошибка "parse error: Expected separator between values" возникает, когда в JSON-файле не соблюдена правильная структура, то есть отсутствует разделитель между значениями или другие ошибки синтаксиса.

Проверьте, что в вашем JSON-файле нет ошибок и соблюдена правильная структура. Убедитесь, что все ключи заключены в кавычки, что каждое значение имеет правильный тип данных, и что между элементами массива или объекта присутствует запятая.

Если вы не можете найти ошибку, попробуйте воспользоваться онлайн-валидатором JSON, например, https://jsonlint.com/. Он может помочь определить место и характер ошибки.

Ответ на комментарий Дмитрий:

> JSON верен. Но когда он используется в команде for запятые отсутсвуют
> C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>for /F "delims=" %i in ('echo {"ID": "31516"
> "phone": "79999999999" "message": "Hello"} | jq ."phone"') do set
> phone=%i

Проблема в том, что команда `echo {"ID": "31516" "phone": "79999999999" "message": "Hello"} | jq ."phone"` не правильно форматирует JSON-файл, убирая запятые между полями. В итоге команда `jq` не может правильно распарсить JSON-файл.

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, вам нужно заключить JSON-файл в кавычки, чтобы он правильно интерпретировался командой echo:

```
for /F "delims=" %i in ('echo "{\"ID\": \"31516\", \"phone\": \"79999999999\", \"message\": \"Hello\"}" | jq ."phone"') do set phone=%i
```

В этом случае команда echo будет выводить JSON-файл, заключенный в двойные кавычки, и `jq` сможет правильно распарсить его.

Comment: Использовал ваш код и выдало ошибку "parse error: Expected separator between values at line 1, column 22"

Comment: @Дмитрий Ответ на Ваш комментарий вложил в свой ответ.

Comment: JSON верен. Но когда он используется в команде for запятые отсутсвуют C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>for /F "delims=" %i in ('echo {"ID": "31516" "phone": "79999999999" "message": "Hello"} | jq ."phone"') do set phone=%i

Comment: @Дмитрий Ответ на Ваш комментарий вложил в свой ответ.

Comment: Запятые появились, но jq все так же не может распарсить for /F "delims=" %i in ('echo "{"ID": "31516", "phone": "79999999999", "message": "Hello"}" | jq ."phone"') do set phone=%i
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "phone"
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6